# What is the force strength measurement unit?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, units

I am just curious what measurement units does blender use for the force filed strength.
An old site mentioned that Wind filed for example uses Newtons. Which is not the case in blender 2.8.2.
I tried to calculate the wind force myself by running some simulations. It seems that 100 units in blender are about 3.5 Newtons.

If anyone knows this, please respond. I need exact numbers for my future simulations.

Comment: are your units all setup correctly? (mass to kg, distance to m, etc?) you can try to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrL0tbBTKus

Comment: yes they are set up correctly in 2.8.2  by default